# OOP javascript object inheritance (parent/child)

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm working with Javascript OOP and I can't get it to work. I want to call functions from another object (parent) via the child. This is my "class" code:

```
function Unit(_x, _y, _speed) {
    this.x = _x;
    this.y = _y;
    this.dx = _speed;
    this.dy = _speed;
    this.gravity = 0;
}
Unit.prototype.apply_gravity = function() {
    this.gravity+=global_gravity;
    this.y+=this.gravity;
}
Unit.prototype.render = function() {
    context.drawImage(images[0], canvas_screen.x+this.x, canvas_screen.y+this.y);
}

function Character() {
}

Character.inheritsFrom(Unit);
```

I want to be able to call the functions: "apply_gravity" and "render" from the character object like this:

```
var character = new Character(100,100,5);
character.render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
Character.inheritsFrom(Unit);
```

with:

```
Character.prototype = new Unit(0,0,0); // or whatever defaults if you want them
```

See this [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/y3aau/)

Comment: I imagine `inheritsFrom` is some 3rd party library (and perhaps used incorrectly if it's [Type.inheritsFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397427.aspx)), although I have no urge to investigate further.